# Анализ сборок дотнета

Tags: c#, .net

Мне необходимо при загрузке дотнет сборки (в виде файла, или набора байтов) на мой сервис получить публичный ключ, которым она подписана, каким образом мне это можно сделать?

Что я пробовал:

1. Загрузить через Assembly.Load её я не могу, так как у неё могут быть зависимые сборки которые тоже должны быть загружены (а их у меня нет).
2. Создать временный аппдомен, загрузить в него сборку через Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad (через маршалинг .DoCallback), а затем выгрузить аппдомен после извлечения публичного ключа. Тут я сталкиваюсь с тем, что даже если я выгружаю аппдомен - у меня периодически падает загрузка пересобранной сборки с той же версией (например для другого фреймворка).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вы можете использовать для этого библиотеку [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) которая так же доступна через NuGet.

```
var assembly = Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("fileName");
var publicKey = assembly.Name.PublicKey;
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю сигнатуру - что оно читает именно определение сборки, не загружая её? И можно ли, заодно, с помощью неё проверить целостность подписи?

Comment: Да, сборка не загружается, а просто читается сам файл. На счет второго вопроса - не уверен.

Comment: @ApInvent: Круто! А я в своё время писал велосипед, который самостоятельно парсил эту же информацию.

Comment: @VladD Да, очень полезная библиотека на самом деле, с большими возможностями ;)